# Why does it return undefined when I try to get the height and width of an image in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to log the height and the width values of an image to the console in react.js but they are (for some reason) undefined. Do you know why it is?

Here's the code:

```
export default function FilmPage(props) {
    const getImgSize = (img) => {
        let imageEl = <img onLoad={()=>{
            console.log(imageEl.width)
            console.log(imageEl.height)
        }} src={img} />

        return imageEl
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="proper-film">
            <div className="body">
                <div>{getImgSize(props.data.image)}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

And also the data I retrieve looks like this:

```
data = {
    some: null,
    other: null,
    stuff: null,  
    image: "https://my_api.com/images/original/picture.jpg",
    and_more: null
}
```

By the way, when I tried debugging, there was no problem with the data I retrieve.

What would you recommend?

Comment: `imageEl` is equal to the return of JSX code,.  You could maybe get this information from doing `<image onLoad={(e) =>` and get the element from e.  But normally accessing DOM elements you use the `useRef` & `useEffect` hooks.

Comment: useEffect(() => { ....}, []) have you tried to place your code into useEffect hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `getImgSize`  method like below

```
const getImgSize = (img) => {
    return <img onLoad={(e) => {
      console.log(e.target.offsetHeight)
      console.log(e.target.offsetWidth)
    }} src={img} />


  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-borg-x474m?file=/src/App.js